# Converting separate "double" values into an Array within an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created a program that contains an ArrayList with separated "double" values for student grades. However, the course calls for creating an int Array of grades, instead of the separate values I had previously.

My code for Student Class (I have deleted irrelevant code to cut to the chase):

```
public class Student {

    private int[] Grades = new int[3];

    public Student(String stuid, String fname, String lname, String email, int age, int[] grades) {
        this.Grades = grades;
    }

    public int[] getGrades() {
        return Grades;
    }

    public void setGrades(int[] grades) {
        Grades = grades;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("StuID: %s\t First Name: %s\t Last Name: %s\t E-Mail: %s\t Age: %s\t Grades: %s\t",
                this.StuID, this.FName, this.LName, this.Email, this.Age, this.Grades);
    }
}
```

Roster Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Roster {
    static ArrayList<Student> studentArray;

    public Roster(ArrayList<Student> ar) {
        studentArray = ar;
    }

    // 3.C - Print Average Grade
    public static void print_average_grade(String studentID) {
        for (Student v : studentArray) {
            if (v.getStuID().equals(studentID)) {
                double total = v.getGrade1() + v.getGrade2() + v.getGrade3();
                double average = total / 3;
                System.out.println("Student ID#" + studentID + " Grade AVG= " + average);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Student> studentArray = new ArrayList<Student>();

        studentArray.add(new Student("1", "John", "Smith", "John1989@gmail.com", 20, 88, 79, 59));
        studentArray.add(new Student("2", "Susan", "Erickson", "Erickson_1990@gmailcom", 19, 91, 72, 85));
        studentArray.add(new Student("3", "Jack", "Napoli", "The_lawyer99yahoo.com", 19, 85, 84, 87));
        studentArray.add(new Student("4", "Erin", "Black", "Erin.black@comcast.net", 22, 91, 98, 82));
        studentArray.add(new Student("5", "Captain", "Planet", "PowIsYours@planet.edu", 65, 99, 98, 97));

        new Roster(studentArray);
        for (Student v : studentArray) {
            print_average_grade(v.getStuID());
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the separated values (Grade1, Grade2, Grade3) into an "int[] Grades" array and modified the constructor and have added the setter and the getter. So, I think the Student class is good to go, however the Roster class, is where I am stuck. Two things:

1) How do I add values of the Grades into the Array that is now a part of the ArrayList?

2) How would I adjust my AVG Grade method to perform the same task as before but with the values of the Array?

Any help would be great because I have been stuck on this for days.

Thanks.

P.S. If posting the full code would be easier, I will gladly post it for any aid on this problem.

Comment: on what exactly are you stuck?  does it not compile, or does it not give expected results.  If former, what are the errors?  If latter, what does it give and what was expected?

Comment: as per your saying grades are double then why are you using int array.Roaster has static studentArray list though ,creating new object.you really need to restructure code

Comment: @DBug How do I add the three Grade values in the Array that is inside the ArrayList in the "studentArray.add" code? For example: studentArray.add(new Student("1","John","Smith","John1989@gmail.com", 20, null)); You see the "null" field? That is the Array within the ArrayList. How do I get input the 3 grades into that "null" field? I hope this is clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix your code according to the two requirements (array, AVG). Please see the following codes (I have tested it).

Student Class:

```
public class Student {

    String StuID;
    String FName;
    String LName;
    String Email;
    int Age;
    private int[] Grades = new int[3];

    public Student(String stuid, String fname, String lname, String email, int age, int[] grades) {
        this.StuID = stuid;
        this.FName = fname;
        this.LName = lname;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Grades = grades;
    }

    public int[] getGrades() {
        return Grades;
    }

    public void setGrades(int[] grades) {
        Grades = grades;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("StuID: %s\t First Name: %s\t Last Name: %s\t E-Mail: %s\t Age: %s\t Grades: %s\t", this.StuID, this.FName, this.LName, this.Email, this.Age, this.Grades);
    }

    public String getFName() {
        return FName;
    }

    public void setFName(String fName) {
        FName = fName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        Age = age;
    }

    public String getStuID() {
        return StuID;
    }

    public void setStuID(String stuID) {
        StuID = stuID;
    }

    public String getLName() {
        return LName;
    }

    public void setLName(String lName) {
        LName = lName;
    }
}
```

Roster Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Roster {
    ArrayList<Student> studentArray;

    public Roster(ArrayList<Student> ar) {
        studentArray = ar;
    }

    // 3.C - Print Average Grade
    public void print_average_grade(String studentID) {
        for (Student v : studentArray) {
            if (v.getStuID().equals(studentID)) {
                double total = v.getGrades()[0] + v.getGrades()[1] + v.getGrades()[2];
                double average = total / 3;
                System.out.println("Student ID#" + studentID + " Grade AVG= " + average);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Student> studentArray = new ArrayList<Student>();

        int[] grades1 = {88, 79, 59};
        int[] grades2 = {91, 72, 85};
        int[] grades3 = {85, 84, 87};
        int[] grades4 = {91, 98, 82};
        int[] grades5 = {99, 98, 97};

        studentArray.add(new Student("1", "John", "Smith", "John1989@gmail.com", 20, grades1));
        studentArray.add(new Student("2", "Susan", "Erickson", "Erickson_1990@gmailcom", 19, grades2));
        studentArray.add(new Student("3", "Jack", "Napoli", "The_lawyer99yahoo.com", 19, grades3));
        studentArray.add(new Student("4", "Erin", "Black", "Erin.black@comcast.net", 22, grades4));
        studentArray.add(new Student("5", "Captain", "Planet", "PowIsYours@planet.edu", 65, grades5));

        Roster r = new Roster(studentArray);
        for (Student v : studentArray) {
            r.print_average_grade(v.getStuID());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Student ID#1 Grade AVG= 75.33333333333333
Student ID#2 Grade AVG= 82.66666666666667
Student ID#3 Grade AVG= 85.33333333333333
Student ID#4 Grade AVG= 90.33333333333333
Student ID#5 Grade AVG= 98.0
```

Comment: @ajbnetworkguy What do you mean by 3.B - is it an additional request (as it is not stated in your original post)? If yes, could you accept this answer first, and then open another question for us to answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: The fix definitely worked as planned. I have adjusted it abit, within the Array. Thanks .However, in my print_all() statement, the Array is printing Hex. I'll ask this in a separate question.

Comment: @ajbnetworkguy Thanks! I would be appreciated if you could "accept" my answer, by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did the same project. Mine is still being graded, so I have no idea if it will pass the first time or not. But maybe it will help someone by my sharing it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Roster {

   public static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // input student grades
        int[] grade0 = {0,0,0}; // filler to make grade array equal to student ID
        int[] grade1 = {88, 79, 59};
        int[] grade2 = {91, 72, 85};
        int[] grade3 = {85, 84, 87};
        int[] grade4 = {91, 98, 82};
        int[] grade5 = {99, 98, 97};

        // input student info
        addStudent(0, "null", "null", "null@null.com", 0, grade0); // filler to align student ID with array number
        addStudent(1, "John", "Smith", "John1989@gmail.com", 20, grade1);
        addStudent(2, "Suzan", "Erickson", "Erickson_1990@gmailcom", 19, grade2);
        addStudent(3, "Jack", "Napoli", "The_lawyer99yahoo.com", 19, grade3);
        addStudent(4, "Erin", "Black", "Erin.black@comcast.net", 22, grade4);
        addStudent(5, "Habib", "Trump", "someemail@mywqu.edu", 42, grade5);

        // printing related subroutines/methods
        Student student = students.get(3); //get student 3 for printing
        System.out.println("Print one student:");
        student.print(); //prints specific student data as per 2.D
        printAllStudents(); //print all students as per 3.B
        print_invalid_emails(); //checks email addresses for proper form as per 3.D
        printAverageGrade(); //print grades as per 3.C    
        remove(); // removes student 5 as per 3.A
        printAllStudents(); // shows student 3 has been removed
        remove(); // shows error as student already removed
    }

    public static void addStudent(int studentID, String firstName, String lastName, String email, int age, int[] grades){
            Student newStudent = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, email, age, grades);
            students.add(newStudent);
    }

    public static void remove(){ // remove student 
            try{
                System.out.println("Remove student: 5 ");
                students.remove(5);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.err.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException: No such student ID");
    }}

    public static void printAverageGrade(){ // print Average Grade
                System.out.println("Print Average Grade: ");
            for(Student eachItem : students){
                double total = eachItem.getgrades()[0] + eachItem.getgrades()[1] + eachItem.getgrades()[2];
                double average = total / 3;
                System.out.println(average);
    }}

    public static void printAllStudents(){ // print All Students
                System.out.println("Print all Students: ");
            for(int i=0; i < students.size(); i++){
                students.get(i).print();    
    }}

    public static void print_invalid_emails(){ // check Email Addresses for proper form
            System.out.println("Check for proper form of email addresses: ");       
            for(Student student : students) {
            if (student.getemail().contains("@") && student.getemail().contains(".") && !student.getemail().contains(" ")){
                System.out.println("Passed format check");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid email address");
            }}
    }}

public class Student extends Roster
{
   private int studentID;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String email;
   private int age;
   private int[] grades = new int[3];

   public Student(int studentID, String firstName, String lastName, String email, int age, int[] grades)
   {
       setstudentID(studentID);
       setfirstName(firstName);
       setlastName(lastName);
       setemail(email);
       setage(age);
       setgrades(grades);
   }           
   public int getstudentID(){
       return studentID;
   }
   public void setstudentID(int studentID)
   {
       this.studentID = studentID;
   }   
   public String getfirstName(){
       return firstName;
   }
   public void setfirstName(String firstName)
   {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }
   public String getlastName(){
       return lastName;
   }
   public void setlastName (String lastName)
   {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }
   public String getemail(){
       return email;
   }
   public void setemail(String email)
   {
       this.email = email;
   }
   public int getage(){
       return age;
   }
   public void setage(int age)
   {
       this.age = age;
   }
   public void setgrades(int[] grades){
       this.grades = grades;
   }
   public int[] getgrades(){
       return grades;
   }
   public void print(){
       System.out.println(
       "Student ID = \t" + getstudentID() + ", \t" +
       "First Name = \t" + getfirstName() + ", \t" +
       "Last Name = \t" + getlastName() + ", \t" + 
       "Email = \t" + getemail() + ", \t" +
       "Age = \t" + getage());
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! My project passed on the first submission!